# Render camera keyframes

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, video-sequence-editor

I have a question about rendering!
I was creating a sequence of images, rendering the content of the keyframes, after I inserted this sequence of images into the video editor's timeline, when I click on render it only renders the content of the timeline, but I would like to render the camera content from the 3d view, to render a new frame and then insert it into the timeline, only at the end, after having rendered all the camera keyframes, will I render the entire timeline content .

Is there a way to make this change in rendering?

I don't know if I was clear enough, but if anything I'll add more information.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render the 3D scene, and not the *Video Sequencer*, disable the *Sequencer* option in the *Output* panel. But the best is probably to create another file where you'll only manage the video editing:

[image]